# Doing a job in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, job-hunting

I am a non-EU citizen, now in Poland. I want to get a temporary packaging worker job in UK.

What is the first thing I need to do now?

As I understand:

(1) Find a [tier-5 sponsor company](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/605099/2017-03-31_Tier_2_5_Register_of_Sponsors.pdf) .

(2) Get a job-offer from that company.

(2) Apply for tier-5 visa for UK.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your very question, asked at the same time on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-have-a-packaging-worker-job-Visa-in-the-UK), received this feedback from David Osofsky (Lives in the UK. Knows more than the average bear):

> You have the order of events correct, but the problem is packaging workers are unlikely to be eligible for a Tier-2 visa. And there are no temporary work visas except for the Tier 5 visas, which are very specific, such as people under 30 from a small list of countries, entertainers, sportsmen, diplomats, or government exchange programmes.
>
> The rules for Tier 2 jobs are that they must be a skilled graduate-level job that pays at least £30,000 or the salary required for the job category, whichever is higher. Also now, employers will have to pay £1,000 per year Skills Charge for each migrant they sponsor, which decreases the chances that the employer will sponsor someone from outside the EU rather than train a UK or EU citizen for the job.